# Permission denied when configuring my module though admin page

Tags: routes

I am following drupal's module development [tutorials](https://www.drupal.org/node/1111212). I am using drupal 7.41 and my operating system is ubuntu.

I am creating a module that list links in the footer section of the page. I am making an admin configuration for my module. I have done everything what the tutorial said and I went to my configuration page, I couldn't see my configuration button of my module in `admin/config/content`. Here is my `hook_menu()` implementation:

```
function footer_links_menu() {
$items = array();

$items['admin/config/content/footer_links'] = array(
    'title' => 'Footer Links',
    'description' => 'Configuration for Footer links posts module',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('footer_links_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

return $items;
}
```

I have manually tried to access to `admin/config/content/footer_links`, I got a permission denied error. However, I was already logged in as the admin.
I have changed the value of `access arguments` to `array('access content')`. And it worked. What was the problem? If I leave my code like this, can others also edit my module through the form? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

`'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),`

into

`'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),`

Comment: Why did this worked? What is the difference from the `array('access administration pages')`?

Comment: It is like `access content` and `create article content`. List of permissions is in table `role_permission`